# Routing with vpn

Tags: vpn, routing

I have a wired problem with my vpn connection to my webserver.
After this serves had some problems they made a restore to a version two weeks old.
Today I found that I cannot load or even ping most of the internet.
Investigating on it with a traceroute I found that every request is sent thru the vpn of my webserver:

I don't understand why that is so; I neither know if it has been so before the server broke or not. The server itself can connect/ping everything.

I have another vpn to another server that doesn't show this strange routing when active. The both .conf files are the same except for the addresses and the certificates.

Question: Why does my system change he routing when activating the vpn to my webserver? How can I investigate on this phenomena?

Thankful for any help.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to anx's inquiry I found the reason in the server's config file :)

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

forces each client to route ALL traffic thrugh the server by pushing a

```
0.0.0.0   10.110.0.5   128.0.0.0    UG   0   0   0 tun1
```

to the client's routing table.

I installed that once for a smartphone vpn (but never used it), not knowing that my desktop is also affected, until it break.
It used to work silently until the server broke and was rebuilt.

Thanks for your help.